# how to use for-each-group by to group values in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am getting below output from database and based on that I have to group by the data based on composite_name and RN elements.

Output coming from Database -

```
    <SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutputCollection>
    <SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
    <FLOW_ID>200239</FLOW_ID>
    <COMPOSITE_NAME>ABC</COMPOSITE_NAME>
    <rn>1</rn>
    </SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
    -<SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
    <FLOW_ID>200247</FLOW_ID>
    <COMPOSITE_NAME>ABC</COMPOSITE_NAME>
    <rn>1</rn>
    </SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
<SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
    <FLOW_ID>200301</FLOW_ID>
    <COMPOSITE_NAME>GHI</COMPOSITE_NAME>
    <rn>1</rn>
    </SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
<SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
    <FLOW_ID>200300</FLOW_ID>
    <COMPOSITE_NAME>GHI</COMPOSITE_NAME>
    <rn>1</rn>
    </SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput>
    </SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutputCollection>
```

I have to perform group by on composite_name and rn so that expected output should be

```
<RRR>
<XYZ>
<COMPOSITE_NAME>abc</COMPOSITE_NAME>
FLOW_ID>200239,200247</FLOW_ID>
</XYZ>
<XYZ>
<COMPOSITE_NAME>GHI</COMPOSITE_NAME>
FLOW_ID>200300,200301</FLOW_ID>
</XYZ>
</RRR>
```

I have used below XSLT but not getting expected output.

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutputCollection/ns0:SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput" group-by="concat(ns0:COMPOSITE_NAME ,'|', ns0:rn)">
     
    

     <tns:EmailBody>
       
           <tns:InterfaceName>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:COMPOSITE_NAME"/>
           </tns:InterfaceName>
           <tns:FaultedId> 
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group">
             <xsl:value-of select="ns0:FLOW_ID"/>
              <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
                 
               
                
              </tns:FaultedId>
        </tns:EmailBody>
        
        
      
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Please help me with correct logic to achieve the output.

Thank you !

Comment: Hello all,
Could you please help me with this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt makes very little sense. It looks like you copied snippets from various sources and thrown them together in random order hoping they will somehow combine themselves into a functioning code. This might work in a Harry Potter film, not in programming.

Try a straightforward textbook approach instead:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutputCollection">
    <RRR>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="SelectFlowIdDetailsFromSOAInfraOutput" group-by="concat(COMPOSITE_NAME ,'|', rn)">
            <XYZ>
                <COMPOSITE_NAME>
                    <xsl:value-of select="COMPOSITE_NAME"/>
                </COMPOSITE_NAME>
                <FLOW_ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/FLOW_ID" separator=","/>
                </FLOW_ID>
            </XYZ>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </RRR>
</xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvgZ